# Maximum size of a poset chain

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $m,n \geq 2$. Consider the poset $(\{1,...,m\}\times \{1,...,n\}, \rho)$ where $\rho $ is defined by $(i,j)\rho (k,l)$ if and only if $i \leq k$ and $j \leq l$.

What is the maximum size of a chain in this poset? What is the maximum size of an antichain in this poset?

I know that the maximum size would be include finding the size of minimum to the maximum or highest up maximal element.  As for the antichain, it would be finding the size of max element to second highest up maximal element.
Any tips?!

Comment: Tip: draw the Hasse diagram.  If you can't do it for general $m,n$ then first try $m=3$, $n=4$.

Comment: What would the Hasse diagram look like? Sorry I'm just really confused about the Cartesian product part

Comment: OK well maybe you should start with $m=n=2$.  Suggest you write down all possible pairs in the Cartesian product (hint: there are $4$ of them).  Then write down all possible statements $x\mathop{\rho}y$ where $x$ and $y$ are pairs (hint: there are $16$ statements).  Then mark every one of these $16$ statements as true or false.  Hopefully that will sort out the Cartesian product and then you can go on to the next part of the question.

Comment: I can't say that your statement "As for the antichain, it would be finding the size of max element to second highest up maximal element" is *wrong*, because I have no idea what you mean by it. Have you been given a definition of "antichain"? Do you mind sharing it with us? What is an antichain?

Answer (score 1):

1. length of the longest chain: $m+n-1$
2. length of the longest antichain: $min\{m,n\}$

The poset is [graded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_poset) or ranked (via $f:(a,b)\to a+b$). Equivalently, every maximal chain has same length. example of a chain: $(1,1)\to (1,2)\to \dots \to (1,n)\to (2,n)\to (3,n)\to \dots \to (m,n)$.

The length of the antichain the largest [whitney number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_poset#The_usual_case) (number of elements with a particular rank).

PS: Writing down the hasse diagram is the best way to get the idea. Although, I have used the facts about 'graded' poset, they easy to prove once the definition is known.